# Error when using Matlab Function block in Simechanics (nested functions and parsing of Matlab function both error)

Tags: robotic-arm, matlab, simulation

I create a simple simulink model using Matlab Function block to calculate angles of 4 dof robotic arm using Robotic toolbox Matlab while input is x, y and z values. I used forward kinematics to calculate angles. Model and error is shown in below images:
[image]
[image]

My code is given below (which is put in matlab funcrion block):

```
function [theta1,theta2,theta3,theta4]=invkin(px,py,pz)
% code to find inverse kinematics solution for 4 dof rootic arm
preach = [px py pz]; % reach point of end-effector
theta1 = 0;  theta2 = 0; theta3 = 0; theta4 = 0;
% create links using D-H parameters
L(1) = Link([ 0 0 0 pi/2 0], 'standard');
L(2) = Link([ 0 .15005 .4318 0 0], 'standard');
L(3) = Link([0 .0203 0 -pi/2 0], 'standard');
L(4) = Link([0 .4318 0 pi/2 0], 'standard');
%define link mass
L(1).m = 4.43;
L(2).m = 10.2;
L(3).m = 4.8;
L(4).m = 1.18;
%define center of gravity
L(1).r = [ 0 0 -0.08];
L(2).r = [ -0.216 0 0.026];
L(3).r = [ 0 0 0.216];
L(4).r = [ 0 0.02 0];
%define link inertial as a 6-element vector
%interpreted in the order of [Ixx Iyy Izz Ixy Iyz Ixz]
L(1).I = [ 0.195 0.195 0.026 0 0 0];
L(2).I = [ 0.588 1.886 1.470 0 0 0];
L(3).I = [ 0.324 0.324 0.017 0 0 0];
L(4).I = [ 3.83e-3 2.5e-3 3.83e-3 0 0 0];
% set limits for joints
 L(1).qlim=[deg2rad(-160) deg2rad(160)];
 L(2).qlim=[deg2rad(-125) deg2rad(125)];
 L(3).qlim=[deg2rad(-270) deg2rad(90)];
 L(4).qlim=[deg2rad(-170) deg2rad(110)];
   %build the robot model
  rob = SerialLink(L, 'name','Puma56');
  qready = [0 -pi/4 pi/4 0]; % initial position of robot
T1= transl(preach); % convert of reach point of 4x4 homogenous matrix
[qreach,err,exitflag] =  rob.ikcon(T1, qready); % find inverse kinematics with error
%rob.fkine(qreach);
theta1 = qreach(1,1);  theta2 = qreach(1,2); theta3 = qreach(1,3); theta4 = qreach(1,4);
end
```

How to solve these errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Constant inputs to a Matlab function to displays... why are you using Simulink at all? Why not just do it all in a Matlab script?

Answer (score 1):

After looking closer at your code, I'll reiterate my comment - why are you doing this in Simulink? I'll make your code briefer for clarity:

```
function [theta]=invkin(px,py,pz)
theta = 0;
L = <const>;
preach = <const>;
rob = f(L);
qready = <const>;
T1= f(preach);
qreach = f(rob,T1,qready);
theta = qreach;
end;
```

So,

1. You aren't using the inputs at all.
2. You're constantly resetting `theta` to zero at the start of the script, so if you did happen to make the inputs time-varying, I don't think the time-varying output would be what you want because you're not progressing through time. Your script would run a complete simulation at every call.

Imagine plotting this from a Matlab script - `plot(time,theta)` - again, there's no time dependence here. You just have one value, `theta`, that describes the joint angles required to achieve the desired end effector position. Your plot would be a horizontal line.

I would imagine this might be contributing to the [trouble you're having implementing the fix you were given](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/330602-error-when-using-matlab-function-block-in-simechanics-nested-functions-and-parsing-of-matlab-functi#comment_438477).

Comment: Sorry @Chuck, by mistake I made _preach = [px py pz]_ as comment while pasting code on here.  Still the error is same.  Your first question is why theta = 0. Because if I don't use theta = 0, matlab give error like _Error in port widths or dimensions. Output port 1 of 'matlabfunik/MATLAB Function/pz' is a one dimensional vector with 1 elements_ .And answer to your second question why I'm using simmechanics because inverse kinematics is first part after getting angle I want to do inverse dynamics of my robot. So, output from this I will used input in inverse dynamics.

Comment: @NaseebGill - You're getting the error in port widths because your code isn't structured to do what you want it to do. The only reason I can think of that you're running this in Simulink is because you're trying to convert your `[px py pz]` to a trajectory (time varying arc) and want to simulate how the robot moves. In order for that to work, though, you need to get the joint angle solution *and apply it to your robot*. You may be *intending* to add some dynamic simulation, but you don't have it yet, so you're left running a static simulation in a dynamic environment.

Answer (score 0):

In Simulink the Matlab embedded function block supports only a subset of the available commands in Matlab. If you want to use external functions, you have to declare these using [coder.extrinsic()](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.extrinsic.html).

If the problem is with nested functions and not with declaring the external function, you could try to de-nest the function, by simply deleting the 'value' function from the file it is defined in and create a new, separate file for the function on the same path. Please keep in mind that this is a workaround, not really a fix.

Comment: Thanks @50k4 for your reply but when used _coder.extrinsic('value')_ in matlab function block, it shows same error. How to remove this. value function is shown below:


`function out = value(v, opt)
                if opt.sym
                    out = sym(v);
            else
                   out = v;
               end
           end`